# JavaFX Exception in thread "WindowsNativeRunloopThread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>

Tags: java, windows, javafx, javafx-8

I just wrote this code here:

```
package SpellcheckerClient;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/controller/gui.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Spellchecker Client");           
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And this is the corresponding controller.

```
package controller;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import spellchecker.remote.SpellcheckerRemoteAdapter;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    TextField input;
    @FXML
    Button send;
    @FXML
    TextArea area;  
    @FXML
    Button connect;

    private SpellcheckerRemoteAdapter adapter;

    @FXML
    private void send() throws RemoteException{
        String toCheck = input.getText();
        this.area.appendText(toCheck + "\n");
        this.area.appendText(checkRoutine(toCheck, this.adapter) + "\n\n");
        this.input.clear();
    }

    public void initiateConnection() {
        try {           
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1088);
            this.adapter = (SpellcheckerRemoteAdapter) registry.lookup(SpellcheckerRemoteAdapter.NAME);
            this.area.appendText("Verbindung erfolgreich aufgebaut!\n");
            connect.setDisable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(this.adapter == null) {
                this.area.appendText("Server nicht gefunden!\n");
            }
        }
    }

    private static String checkRoutine(String input, SpellcheckerRemoteAdapter adapter) throws RemoteException {
        if (input == null || input.isEmpty()) {
            return "Bitte etwas eingeben!";
        }
        String[] words = input.split(" ");
        boolean control = true;
        String output = "";
        for(String word : words) {
            if(!adapter.check(word)) {
                control = false;
                output += word + ":\t" + adapter.getProposal(word) + "\n";
            }
        }
        if(control) {
            return "Alles Okay!\n";
        }
        return output;
    }


}
```

If I run this code on my Laptop, where I wrote it, it runs perfectly fine in Eclipse and as runnable Jar. However, if I try to run the JAR on another computer i receive this error message:

```
Exception in thread "WindowsNativeRunloopThread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.staticScreen_getScreens(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.initScreens(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.lambda$run$1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 

Exception in thread "WindowsNativeRunloopThread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: <init>
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.staticScreen_getScreens(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Screen.initScreens(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.lambda$run$1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline.getAdapterOrdinal(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.assignScreensAdapters(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runToolkit(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$startup$10(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.Application.lambda$run$1(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

On my Laptop and my Computer are the same Versions of the JDK/JRE installed.
I don't really get what the error message is telling me.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with [tag:rmi].

Comment: Which version of the JDK _is_ this? Is it 10? Looks like a broken installation with missing native libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Hello I have the same issue on my Eclipse environnement (Windows 10 OS),
adding in VM option -Djava.library.path="C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin" solved my problem

That means that javafx-graphics-[version]-win.jar call some native dll. And You have to found were those dll is stored.
I found the path, thanks to jvisualvm and showing the VM option for the case where it's the application run correctly.

Hoping that it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Which JDk you have installed?? I have the same issue and i use JDK 8 instead of JDK 9. Which helped me.[Sample Image of Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqpU8.jpg)

This is because jar which i created it was created on JDK 8 through a different system. 
Where as when it was executing on another system which has JDK9. So it is version incompatible.

After keeping single JDK 8 and mapped it to system environment when i try to run my jar it worked for me.

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this error may cause java sub versions. For example, I need java 1.8.0_221 version but the system 1.8.0_341. Therefore, I got same exception and changed the environment settings.

Comment: So the error causes java subversions? Probably reverse...

Comment: I know java has backward compatibility but some cases i saw this possible.

Comment: Yes, I saw this error cause a java subversion.